# How to sign in substrate in an mobile app?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I am planning to build an substrate android app using webview or react native. But one can't use polkadot extension for sign in in an android app. So what are the ways to sign in a substrate app in mobile?

Comment: What do you mean by sign in? Access account balances and send transactions? You could use [polkadot-js](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api) to access a node.

Comment: Yes, access account balances and send transactions.

Comment: I don't get, where to store the seed phrase?

Comment: You should probably look at the Parity Signer project, which is an android app which exactly does this stuff: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-signer